# Prevent ASP.NET Menu from appearing in a new line

Tags: asp.net, css, menu

I've got a page with rows of image buttons representing various functionality.
I'd like to add a `Menu` at the end of each row that will represent extra dynamic configurable actions.

How can I make the root menu item appear after the image buttons in the same row
instead of appearing in the row/line below? I tried with:

```
.Menu {display: inline-block;}
```

but it doesn't really make any difference....

Comment: Could you post the HTML that is generated by the menu please?

Comment: in fact I cannot really, not enough space... it's an asp:menu after an asp:imagebutton within a cell of a repeater.

Comment: doesn't it work with just display:inline;, it's a terribly wild guess and any other guess will be just as wild since we have no idea what does your html or css looks like at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `<asp:menu>`, but I just played around with one.  Looks like it renders as an html `<table>` by default, with each item contained in a `<td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;">`.

The 100% width is probably forcing it to a new line.  Change the style declaratively in design view, programmatically in the code-behind, or override it via a stylesheet.